# Is it possible to create one string from single characters?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a single string from single characters selected from another table in a for loop. Is there a way to do this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_TRIGGER_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLE_TABLE_TABLE FOR EACH ROW
declare
  text_length number(10);
  rus_temp varchar2(10);
  latin_temp varchar2(10);
  mc_temp varchar(55);
begin
  begin

      text_length := length(:new.mc);
      mc_temp := (NULL);
      for i in 1..text_length
      LOOP
        letter_temp := (null);
        latin_temp := (null);
        rus_temp := SUBSTR(:new.mc, i, 1);
        select LATINLETTERS INTO latin_temp from LETTERSAPPROXIMATION where rus_temp = RUSSIANLETTERS;

    -- HOW TO ADD UP SELECTED LETTERS INTO ONE STRING        

      END LOOP;

    end if;
  end;
END;
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table's structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get

Comment: I cannot put much data because it's confidential to my company: but I have a table with fields storing a short text in Russian language as varchar2. Then I have to convert it into somewhat approximation in Latin letters. I created a table with Latin letters with corresponding Russian symbols. I know how to iterate through string using SUBSTR and for loop. Then using SELECT INTO get a letter I'm interested in. But I don't know how to put them together as a new string.

Comment: Even if you can not post you actual data, you can build a small example to better explain what you have and what you need to get. Have a look at [mcve]

Comment: Please include a [fake] table structure with some [fake] data so we can help you. You want answers, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you simply need to concatenate, something like:

```
for i in select someChar from ... loop
  vString := vString || i.someChar;
end loop
```

Another way, without the loop, could be by [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466), for example:

```
select listagg(someChar) within Group (order by ...) from ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Concatenate works perfectly. I'm quite fresh in Oracle PL\SQL and I don't know most of the functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a for loop for this?  Just use `rpad()`.  Something like this:

```
select rpad(SUBSTR(:new.mc, i, 1), text_length, SUBSTR(:new.mc, i, 1)
into mc_temp
```